# Trouble Sending iOS push notifications from Google App Engine

Tags: python, ios, google-app-engine, apple-push-notifications

I'm working on my first iOS app that uses push notifications. I have a python script that lets me to send push notifications from my machine but I'm unable to get this working with the Google App Engine Launcher.

When I run this on GAE I get nothing - no errors and no push notifications. What am I doing wrong? I know the code for sending the actual notification is working properly but I'm not able to duplicate this on Google's servers.

Here is the script I'm trying to run with GAE Launcher:

```
import os
import cgi
import webapp2

from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app

import ssl
import json
import socket
import struct
import binascii

TOKEN = 'my_app_token'
PAYLOAD = {'aps': {'alert':'Push!','sound':'default'}}

class APNStest(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def send_push(token, payload):
        # Your certificate file
        cert = 'ck.pem'

        # APNS development server
        apns_address = ('gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com', 2195)

        # Use a socket to connect to APNS over SSL
        s = socket.socket()
        sock = ssl.wrap_socket(s, ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv3, certfile=cert)
        sock.connect(apns_address)

        # Generate a notification packet
        token = binascii.unhexlify(token)
        fmt = '!cH32sH{0:d}s'.format(len(payload))
        cmd = '\x00'
        message = struct.pack(fmt, cmd, len(token), token, len(payload), payload)
        sock.write(message)
        sock.close()

    send_push(TOKEN, json.dumps(PAYLOAD))

application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
                                       ('/apns', APNStest)
                                       ], debug=True)

def main():
run_wsgi_app(application)

if __name__ == "__main__":
main()
```

Comment: Do you get any errors? Perhaps your `ck.pem` file is not located in the correct folder.

Comment: @Eran - I'm not getting any errors which is making it difficult to debug. I'm pretty sure my .pem file is in the right spot because the same script works when run locally.

Comment: Sorry if this is noob:ish, but shouldn't you have a get-method in APNStest? I'm not that into Python, but I guess that code is executed once only, when the class is loaded or something like that. Maybe it's being called to soon for the GAE socket stuff in "production mode"..? :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution was very simple as I expected. I had enabled billing for the project on cloud.google.com but needed to have billing enabled at appengine.google.com as well. Stupid mistake that set me back 2 days.

Comment: ya you need to enable billing more than one place, but in my case it is still not working now I have this error: ` com.google.cloud.backend.pushnotification.PushFeedbackProcessingServlet doGet: Retrieving the list of inactive devives failed with CommunicationException:javapns.communication.exceptions.CommunicationException: Problem communicating with Feedback service `